# Dynamically create Public Properties

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, properties

How dan I dynamically create some public properties on a custom webcontrol.

For example, web control has 5 TextBox controls. I need a public property for each TextBox control to be able to set a specific property of the TextBox control.

I want to be able to loop the controls in the webcontrol and create a public property for each TextBox control.

any ideas?

Comment: You could make them Public, then you could access them from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

If the child-controls are present at Design-Time then you need to explain *why* you want to dynamically add properties to access the control members--unless there is a good reason it just sounds like a poor design.

Here's my suggestion:

- Leave your controls as `Friend` or `Private` -- don't expose them directly (it leads to tight-coupling and gets nasty over time).
- Expose a new public property that gets/sets the corresponding property on 1x of your controls; so if you want to set `.Text` on 5x TextBoxes you'll have 5x properties.
- Be done with it.

If you're trying to be clever by dynamically adding them, then it's a good intention that will lead to poor results.  Just remember: KISS (Keep it simple, stupid!).

Comment: Then why dynamically add the properties--just add their related properties to the class--in the property setters update corresponding control value.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a property like this

```
    private TextBox[] textBoxes; //declared as a class member variable

    public TextBox[] TextBoxes
    {
        get
        {
            if (textBoxes == null)
            {
                textBoxes =(from ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
                            where ctrl is TextBox
                            select (TextBox)ctrl).ToArray();
            }
            return textBoxes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As long as you're not trying to set the collection of textBoxes with this method you should still be ok even though this property is readonly. You would do something like `myControl.TextBoxes[0].Text = "Test";`

Comment: This will work, but why not just expose the controls as `Public`... Personally I would advice against *both* approaches--exposing controls is wide-open for abuse and bad usages.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the controls contained in a WebContol (or any class for that matter) is not a good design as it makes your code brittle and hard to maintain. You should put code that directly manipulates the TextBoxes inside the WebControl.